# Fit an autoregressive model on a heteroscedastic time-series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive, statsmodels, differencing

I have a time-series that I want to model using an autoregressive process using [`statsmodel`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg) for benchmarking purposes. This time-series is not stationary: visual inspection and both the adfuller unit-root test and the stationary kpss test shows this very clearly. In addition, its partial autocorrelation values are completely unstable: they are important on a very large number of lags, and for some lags, the autocorrelation is even much higher than +/-1.

This unstable behaviour in the partial autocorrelation is by the way already something I have trouble interpreting... But by applying the differentiator operator once, we get a well-formed time-series, stationary according to adfuller and kpss statistical tests, and homoscedastic. This differentiated time-series also have well-behaved partial autocorrelation values, converging to zero in about ten lags or so.

[image]
[image]

Given that `statsmodel.Autoreg.fit()` provides (A) a (default) fit estimator assuming serie's homoskedasticity but also (B) heteroskedasticity-autocorrelation robust covariance estimator, my question is whether it makes more sense to fit the original series (using est. B) or the differentiated series (using default estimator)? In case I am using the differentiated series, how can I then use the fitted parameters to perform forecasts on the original series?

Comment: It is *series*, not *serie*, even in the singular form. Also, it is pretty clear that the series does not have a unit root, so differencing is unwarranted and the augmented Dickey-Fuller test should not be indicating a unit root. Also, if the second graph depicts the differentiated time series, then it is pretty clear it is heteroskedastic.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sure agree. But my question was how to fit the model. Is it better to use the differentiated one or the original one? Then in case I am using the differentiated one, how can I forecast values on the original series using the parameters of the differentiated one?